# Auto expand Liquid slider height when content height is added after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, height

[image]

**After click the "Click" button**
[image]

From the above images, you can see that the box is cropped after click. I want the Liquid Slider auto expand when I click the button to add the height of the box.

Understand that this slider come with the auto height function that detect the height of the content. But it doesn't work if I added `$(".bxspace1").animate({height: "+=15"});`

I refer the code from Liquid Slider, you can check [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Responsive-jQuery-Content-slider-with-HTML5-Liquid%20Slider.html). Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

```js
$('#slider-id').liquidSlider({
  hoverArrows: false,
 dynamicArrows: true,
});


function increaseFontSize1() {
  $(".bxspace1").animate({height: "+=15"});
}
```

```css
.ctnbox2 a{width: 196px; float:left; border:3px solid #75b653; margin: 0 6px; background-color:#fff; color: #75b653; }
.bxspace1{height: 200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Content-slider-with-HTML5-Liquid%20Slider/js/jquery.liquid-slider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Content-slider-with-HTML5-Liquid%20Slider/css/liquid-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="javascript:increaseFontSize1()">Click</a>

<div class="liquid-slider"  id="slider-id">
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 1</h2>
    <div class="ctnbox2">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="bxspace1">
          <div class="tiwbckg">
            <div class="floatleft condo"></div>
            <div class="floatleft">
              <h2 class="maintitle1"><main_content>Condominium</main_content><br/><br/></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="boxtxt1">
            <div class="boxtitle"><main_content>Sed Congue Egestas</main_content></div>
            <p><main_content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nec augue a lorem iaculis vehicula.</main_content></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 2</h2>
    <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
  </div>          
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 3</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 4</h2>
    <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So easy but I never realized, just use the same method and apply it to `class="liquid-slider"`.

```
$('.liquid-slider').animate({height: "+=10"});
```